Cohen's Kappa for repeated-measures binary variables
I conducted an experiment in which I showed two types of advertising messages: the first type has a rational style, the second has an emotional style. The sample was exposed to these messages several times (repeated measures) and each time I administered a questionnaire asking whether the message was rational or emotional. So I have a 2x2 matrix where variable 1 is the type of message (rational/emotional) and variable 2 is the recognition of the message (rational/emotional). So both variables are binary nominal categorical.
I would like to do a manipulation check to see if the subjects correctly identified the message style, what kind of concordance test should I use? I was thinking about Cohen's kappa, but in my case I have repeated measures and I have read that this may not be the right test.

Why did you expose the same participants to the same 2 messages, multiple times, and collect feedback, multiple times. Your observations are now (highly) correlated, which complicates the matter. What was the motivation?

Thank you very much for the question jginestet. There were 4 messages, but they can be categorized into two types (rational and emotional). More precisely: there were 2 rational messages (the content of these messages differed, but both had a rational tone) and 2 emotional messages (again, the content differed, but the tone was emotional). Although there were therefore 4 messages, it was important for me to measure the two styles. I hope I have been clearer.

Thanks. And then, why did each subject see the same 4 messages several times? Or was it a different set of 4? I.e. why the repeated measures?

Thanks for asking jginestet. I confirm your initial interpretation: the four messages exhibited diverse content, categorized into rational and emotional types. This selection aimed to experimentally control message content bias by enhancing variability. This method parallels the validation process for logos, applicable to video advertisements as well. For instance, to evaluate the impact of familiar versus unfamiliar brand logos, utilizing one of each would suffice; however, employing multiple logos enhances content control through greater variability.

You wrote "The sample was exposed to these messages several times (repeated measures)"; does that mean that a subject saw the same 4 messages multiple times? Or was it a different set of 4? If the same, why did you do that? Subjects are unlikely to give a different answer the 2nd time?

Sorry for my error in clarity. Each subject was exposed to only 4 messages (2 rational and 2 emotional), for each message they indicated, on a recognition scale, whether it was rational or emotional (on a nominal scale). I wrote for repeated measures for two reasons: 1) in the dataset, each subject is repeated in 4 rows (one row for each message); 2) I thought that comparing the message one is exposed to with the nominal recognition scale was an within-subjects design

I'm not sure the best option but I'm pretty sure this would be a valid approach:
Intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) is common statistic used to assess the agreement between 2 numeric variables, but has also been extended to handle categorical variables, even with repeated measures like your case:
Stoffel, Martin A., Shinichi Nakagawa, and Holger Schielzeth. "rptR: Repeatability estimation and variance decomposition by generalized linear mixed‐effects models." Methods in Ecology and Evolution 8.11 (2017): 1639-1644.
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rptR/index.html

I thank you very much for your help jarbet, I will follow the suggestion you gave me

One could deal with your data as a 2x2 confusion matrix. As the provided wiki link shows, from it you can derive all sorts of metrics; TPR and TNR are probably the most basic ones, and they will tell you how well the subjects recognized the rational and emotional messages (you decide wether "emotional" is negative or positive). That seems to be what you would like to accomplish.
Then you have PPV and NPV, but since in your case the prevalence is .5 (same # of emotional and rational messages), this really does not tell you anything more than TPR and FNR. You can also look at overall Accuracy, but again because prevalence=.5, it is just the average of TPR and TNR. And you can try other metrics (e.g. F1), as desired. One advantage of TPR and TNR is that they are binomial proportions, and thus you can use simple binomial CI's to obtain confidence intervals. I would probably just stick with these 2, in yor case (all the other metrics are just manipulation of TPR and TNR, but really do not provide any new information; because with prevalence=.5, when you know TP and TN, you can deduce FP and FN, and that is the whole matrix. You really only have 2 degrees of freedom, so 2 metrics describe the whole dataset).
Now, the above assumes that the subjects were presented 1 message at a time, and scored all 4 separately (as opposed to being presented as 2 pairs, each containing one of each type). Then each subject scored 4 separate messages, and could have scored all 4 as "emotional", or 3 out of 4, etc... If the data was presented as pairs, then whenever subjects got the 1 right in the pair, they also got the other one right (similarly for 1 wrong). So now all you have is a count of "correct pairs" vs. incorrect ones. So a single binomial proportion, and the best you can do probably is a binomial CI.
You may be worried about some correlation between measurements (the same subject scored 4 messages); but these messages are different, so you can treat them as independent. This is what is done routinely when "experts" are scoring various samples; the results are aggregated. And while the same subject provides 4 scores, these are for 4 different messages. So I would not worry about repeated measures. The worse that would be is that the CI's of the binomial proportions you obtain are narrower than they should be (if you had used 4 times the number of subjects, each scoring only a single message).
From that same 2x2 confusion matrix, you can extract a Cohen kappa value. But that measures how the subjects agreed, not really how correct they were (even though $\kappa=-1$ would mean complete agreement, but all assessments were wrong, as opposed to $\kappa=1$ where there is full agreement, and all the asse4ssmentgs are correct).
